# JQuery .show() works only from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, two.js

I am trying to write a simple game using two.js. I have a function which is called either from button click event and from game loop:

```
function endGame(gameLoop){
    showStartGame();
    gameLoop.pause();
    $("#gameSquare svg:first").remove();
    $("#startGame").show();
}
```

The line `$("#startGame").show()` executes correctly only when called from the event, the rest works perfectly fine in both cases.

Click event handler:

```
$("#abandonGame").click(function(){
  endGame(two);
  gameLoopPaused = true;
  gameStarted = false;
});
```

The call that doesn't work properly(this.update() is called inside game loop):

```
this.update = function(){
var computedVector = new Two.Vector(0,0);
screens.forEach(function(screen){
screen.update(speed);
screen.getRectangles().forEach(function(item){
  computedVector.x = item.rect.translation.x;
  computedVector.y = item.rect.translation.y + screen.getPosition().y;
  if(computedVector.distanceTo(new Two.Vector(ship.getX(), ship.getY())) < latura + 20)
    endGameEvent();
});
```

Comment: What does the click event handler look like?

Comment: @EduardMalakhov I have added it.

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: Then how do you call endGame when it doesn't work?

Comment: @DuongDang Nope

Comment: Try to call  $("#startGame").show(); to see whether it works or not

Comment: @DuongDang When I call it from $(document).ready event handler it works just fine.

Comment: Game loop is also placed inside $(document).ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the parent of $("#startGame"), it was hidden as well. It worked with event because by the time I was hitting the $("#abandonGame") button It was displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping it in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#startGame").show();
});
```

You can't call show() on an object before it exists